# What is this hanging plant with variegated leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, plant-recommendations

I won this plant and hanging basket at a local dance club, I was so swept up in the excitement of winning I forgot to ask what it’s called.

So what have I got and how should I care for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a variegated Hoya plant.  It is a trailing plant that is fairly easy to care for.  It like bright light, but will tolerate most indoor growing conditions.  It has thick almost succulent leaves, so it is best to treat it like you would a succulent.  Allow it to dry out before giving it water again.  Water less in winter than in summer.
Hoya are collectible plants for their amazing flower.  It will only bloom if you provide it with bright light.  In most indoor conditions it does not bloom.  If you are in the Northern Hemisphere keep in a south facing window in winter (North window for Southern Hemisphere) and an east facing window in summer or a bright but indirect light of a west facing window in summer.

[Hoya Plants at Costa Farm](http://www.costafarms.com/plants/wax-plant)

[Wiki How to care for your hoya with 3 methods](https://www.wikihow.com/Care-for-a-Hoya-Plant)